# Timeline of Twitter list of users: command line utility?

Tags: macos, twitter, command-line

Is there a command-line tool allowing to fetch a timeline of a private list of users on Twitter?

I'm normally using python-twitter-toolbox, but using a native search query [list:my_screen_name/list_name] returns zero results, which likely means that Twitter allows fetching timeline for lists only with a dedicated call, [list/statuses](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/get-lists-statuses.html)--which python-twitter-toolbox doesn't seem to support.

Answer (score 0):

If python-twitter-toolbox doesn't support lists, I suggest you use [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy).

That has [built in support for lists](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.6.0/api.html#API.list_timeline)

`API.list_timeline(username, list_name)`

Comment: Does it have a command line wrapper out of the box for the method you mentioned?

Comment: If you want pure command line, try using https://github.com/twitter/twurl/